# Converting from list format to matrix showing equality

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert from a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
Item | Country
A | UK
B | FR
C | DE
D | FR
```

And I want to create a matrix that compares each item to each other item based on country, so:

```
  A B C D
A 1 0 0 0
B 0 1 0 1
C 0 0 1 0
D 0 1 0 1
```

I feel like this should be possible using some sort of pandas pivot but I can't find the right way

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = df.merge(df, on='Country')
df = pd.crosstab(df['Item_x'], df['Item_y'])
print (df)
Item_y  A  B  C  D
Item_x            
A       1  0  0  0
B       0  1  0  1
C       0  0  1  0
D       0  1  0  1
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! Now to get around the memory error caused by the 31k items...

Comment: @SebastianFSA - For you failed second `crosstab` ? Or `merge` ?

Comment: The merge. It creates a dataframe with 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 31000 rows which is throwing the error. I think it's something I can work around with larger memory limits though!

Comment: @SebastianFSA - unfortunately I have no idea, maybe somebody post another answer.

Comment: @jezrael please update the question with the memory limit issue